# mysql condition based query

Tags: mysql

```
id  mem_id   tran_date  tran_type   tran_points plus_minus
-----------------------------------------------------------
 1    2     2011-10-19    test           50         +
 2    2     2011-10-19    test           50         +  
 3    3     2011-10-19    test           50         +
 4    2     2011-10-19    test           15         -
```

For every individual member all the values in `tran_points` needs to be added when data in `plus_minus` column = '+' and the sum of value in tran_points needs to be substracted when data in plus_minus = '-'

I want to have the following output :

```
member_id   points_balance
--------------------------
   2            85
   3            50
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the table below:

```
CREATE TABLE t_test
 (a INTEGER,
  b INTEGER,
  c VARCHAR(1)
 );
```

and for the entries below:

```
INSERT INTO t_test values(1,50,'+');
INSERT INTO t_test values(1,30,'+');
INSERT INTO t_test values(1,15,'-');
INSERT INTO t_test values(2,30,'+');
INSERT INTO t_test values(2,40,'+');
```

This query works as you expected:

```
SELECT a,SUM((CONCAT(c,b)) +0) as t FROM t_test group by a;

a   t
1   65
2   70
```

Comment: Can u please help me why you have put " +0 " in SUM() ?

Comment: @SandeepBajoria To ensure that strings converted to integers. i.e string '+50' is converted to integer 50, therefore it can sum integers.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a SUM(IF()) type of clause as follows;

```
SELECT mem_id AS member_id, 
    SUM( IF(plus_minus="+", tran_type, (0 - tran_type) ) ) AS points_balance
FROM your_table
GROUP BY member_id
```

Hope that helps :)

Comment: Dave Rix i accepted the answer given by reader_1000. Your solution worked, but just by comparing the amount of code and the logic. it went to reader_1000. anyway thanks........

Comment: OK :( but remember that when you get to hundreds of thousands of rows, mine will be faster as the other one is converting strings to numerics and then performing the calculations, which is slower than simple numerical calculations.....

Answer (score 0):

Similar to the answer

SELECT member_id,
    SUM( CASE WHEN plus_minus='+' THEN tran_type ELSE  (-1) *  tran_type) END)  AS points_balance
FROM tableX
GROUP BY member_id

P.S. In some DB's tran_type should be float or double..

Answer (score 0):

Can you try the below mentioned sql. You dnt need to use the if condition.
SELECT mem_id AS member_id, 
    SUM( tran_type) AS points_balance
FROM your_table
GROUP BY member_id

Answer (score 0):

You can also use

```
SELECT b.mem_id,SUM(b.tran_points)-(SELECT COALESCE(SUM(a.tran_points),0) FROM tableX AS a WHERE a.plus_minus='-' AND a.mem_id=b.mem_id) AS tran_points FROM tableX AS b WHERE b.plus_minus='+' GROUP BY b.mem_id
```